# Is it possible to put HTML in an ASP.NET .ashx file?

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I am wondering it is possible to place html/javascript/etc in a .ashx file. I tried doing this, and I am getting the error "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

The reason I want to do this, is because I am trying to implement photoswipe (http://www.photoswipe.com). Photoswipe needs some special CSS, which I think I am losing when I go into the .ashx file. I want to be able to add some HTML to it to point at the CSS file that I think I am losing.

Edit: here is an example of what my markup looks like. When I click on the href, I am brought to a new page with ".ashx?QueryStringParms=blah" in the browser. Here is where I believe I am losing my CSS.

```
    <div style="text-align:center;" class="gallery-page" data-role="content">
    <ul id="gallery" class="gallery" style="max-height: 75%;">
        <li style="height: 120px; width: 93px; padding-bottom: 2px;"><a href="../Utilities/ImageHandler.ashx?QueryStringParms=blah rel="external"><img src="../Utilities/ImageHandler.ashx?QueryStringParms=blah" /></a></li></ul></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Then use an aspx page...

Comment: You could have the handler write the correct HTML tags for the css/js files you need.

Comment: `context.Response.Write("<script src='blah.js'></script>");`

Comment: Bartdude, I am getting my images returned to my as byte arrays. From what I read, I need to use the .ashx file to render the image. Can you point me to an example that shows how I can do this with an aspx page?

Comment: @Dave > from what I understood, you need to keep your ashx page for rendering images, and simply use that ashx URL into your img tag source attribute. The html generating the img tags aswell as the rest of the HTML of your page should then handle the display of your CSS/javascript content.

Comment: Brad, I tried doing that, but I just end up with a broken image every time.

Comment: @Bartdude > Thanks for the response. I have updated my question to include an example of what my markup looks like. The image thumbnail is the "src" of the "img" tag. The full image is in the "href". When I click the thumbnail, I go to just the ImageHandler.ashx page, and the CSS is lost.

Comment: Indeed... your href should point to an aspx page in which you'd put the CSS/javascript you want + an img tag with the ashx URL you're currently using as href.

Comment: @Bartdude > Thanks! I will give that a try and post back the results.

Comment: I made it an answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this :

```
<div style="text-align:center;" class="gallery-page" data-role="content">
<ul id="gallery" class="gallery" style="max-height: 75%;">
    <li style="height: 120px; width: 93px; padding-bottom: 2px;"><a href="bigimage.aspx?QueryStringParms=blah rel="external"><img src="../Utilities/ImageHandler.ashx?QueryStringParms=blah" /></a></li></ul></div>
```

and then, in your bigimage.aspx file, you'd have some HTML (the CSS and javascript you may need) + an image tag :

```
<img src="../Utilities/ImageHandler.ashx?QueryStringParms=blah" />
```

I presume the querystring params indicate which image you want and the needed size

Comment: Thanks Bartdude. The CSS is now coming through, unfortunately the missing CSS is not what was causing my problem. Oh well, at least I know that is not it. Time to open a new question. Thanks for your help.